Identify a movie or television show, about a creature, or robot, that attaches a device to a featureless head, and creates an ear, or a nose?
When I was younger - say, 25 - 30 years ago - I remember seeing somewhere, I think as a tv-edited movie (could have been a tv show), or made-for-cable back then (like HBO or cinemax), a movie that I would like to see again if anyone can help me identify.
The feature scene in the movie was that there was a humanoid creature, or a robot, or cyborg that had a featureless face.
The creature was using some sort of device to shape the features into his face, like on his ear, or nose.

The Questor Tapes, a Gene Roddenberry TV movie from 1974.  It features an android:

Vaslovik had developed plans to build a superhuman android. A team of
  the world's foremost experts is able to build the android even though
  they do not understand the components with which they are working —
  they are only able to follow the instructions and install the parts
  left by Vaslovik, who has disappeared.

The android is featureless when it is created, but creates features for itself as you describe:

However, once left alone, the android comes to life. It adds the
  various cosmetic touches to a previously featureless outer skin,
  transforming itself from an "it" to a "him"

Sorry, can't find any video online.

Amazing, yep, this was it!
